# Android write to file

Tags: android, file

I've made I simple function to write from URL to file. Everything works good until out.write(), I mean there's no exception, but it just doesn't write anything to file

Here's code

```
private boolean getText(String url, String name) throws IOException {
    if(url!=null){
        FileWriter fstream = new FileWriter(PATH+"/"+name+".txt");
        BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(fstream);
        URL _url =  new URL(url);
        int code = ((HttpURLConnection) _url.openConnection()).getResponseCode();
        if(code==200){
            URLConnection urlConnection = _url.openConnection(); //
            InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(urlConnection.getInputStream());
            int bytesRead = 0;
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            while ((bytesRead = in.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                    String chunk = new String(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                    out.write(chunk);
            }

            return true;
        }
        out.close();

    }
    return false;
}
```

Can someone tell me what's wrong please?

Comment: yes it is, and its empty

Comment: also, all permisions are set and so on - i've already done writing images and thought text will be much easier but im getting real frustrated right now

Comment: Is there anything being read? (Does the while loop get executed?)

Comment: read yes, chunk string has a proper value, but ouw.write doesnt write chunk, got no idea why

Answer (score 3):

Try `fstream.flush()`.

Also `out.close()` should be called before returning from a function.